# Applet Not Initialized in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

Reinstalling Eclipse, and when I attempt to run my Applet(using Proclipsing), the AppletViewer displays a blank white screen with "Start: applet not initialized". Can anyone help me resolve this? Any help is much appreciated.

```
package cells;

import processing.core.PApplet;


public class Cells extends PApplet {
    public float vy=4;
    public float vx=4;
    public void setup() {
        frameRate(100);
        size(1000, 1000);
        background(100);
    }

    public void draw() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
PApplet.main(new String[]{"Package name/Package location + name"});
```

in your

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```